# position a label closer to a particular box in a flow chart in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to position the label `No` closer to the box `check if flag set`. What option should I use.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{connector} = [circle, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm, text centered, text width=1cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (p0) [] {foo(K)};
\node (p1) [process, below of=p0, text width=3cm] {search for key K};
\node (p2) [process, below of=p1, yshift=-1cm, text width=3.5cm] {Create key K for insertion};
\node (p3) [process, below of=p2, yshift=-1cm, text width=3.5cm] {Attempt to insert};
\node (retF) [process, right of=p1, xshift=3cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {return false};
\node (p4) [process, below of=p3, yshift=-1cm, text width=3cm] {check if flag set};
\node (retT) [process, right of=p3, xshift=3cm, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {return true};
\node (h1) [connector, below of=p4, yshift=-1cm] {bar()};



\draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=west] {K not found} (p2);
\draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=south] {K found} (retF);
\draw [arrow] (p2) -- node {} (p3);
\draw [arrow] (p3) -- node[anchor=east] {failed} (p4);
\draw [arrow] (p3) -- node[anchor=south] {successful} (retT);
\draw [arrow] (p4) -- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (h1);
\draw [arrow] (p4.west) -- ++(-1,0) |- node[anchor=south] {No} (p1.west);
\draw [arrow] (h1.west) -- ++(-2.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {} (p1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like

```
\draw [arrow] (p4.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[anchor=south,pos=0.5] {No} |- (p1.west);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{ 
process/.style={
  rectangle, 
  minimum width=2cm, 
  minimum height=1cm, 
  align=center, 
  text width=2cm,
  draw
  },
connector/.style={
  circle, 
  minimum width=1cm, 
  minimum height=0.5cm, 
  align=center, 
  text width=1cm, 
  draw
},
arrow/.style={
  thick,
  ->,
  >=stealth
}
}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm and 2cm
]
\node (p0) [] {foo(K)};
\node (p1) [process, below = 0.2cm of p0, text width=3cm] {search for key K};
\node (p2) [process, below =of p1, text width=3.5cm] {Create key K for insertion};
\node (p3) [process, below =of p2,text width=3.5cm] {Attempt to insert};
\node (retF) [process, right =of p1,, text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {return false};
\node (p4) [process, below =of p3, text width=3cm] {check if flag set};
\node (retT) [process, right =of p3,text width=1cm, minimum width=1cm] {return true};
\node (h1) [connector, below =of p4] {bar()};

\draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=west] {K not found} (p2);
\draw [arrow] (p1) -- node[anchor=south] {K found} (retF);
\draw [arrow] (p2) -- node {} (p3);
\draw [arrow] (p3) -- node[anchor=east] {failed} (p4);
\draw [arrow] (p3) -- node[anchor=south] {successful} (retT);
\draw [arrow] (p4) -- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (h1);
\draw [arrow] (p4.west) -- ++(-1,0) node[anchor=south,pos=0.5] {No} |- (p1.west);
\draw [arrow] (h1.west) -- ++(-2.5,0) |- node[anchor=south] {} (p1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I change `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/3954)), and also I changed the problematic `of=` syntax to `=of` with the positioning library (see).

Comment: perfect. Thank you!! And any reason why `\tikzstyle` should be changed to `\tikzset`?

Comment: @arunmoezhi You're welcome. Regarding your question, ṕlease see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/3954

Comment: And one more question. If my text on the arrows are long, they don't get wrapped up. For example if I change the arrow `successful` to `it was successful` it messes up the flow chart

Comment: @arunmoezhi either declare an `align` option (requires manual line breaks) and/or a `text width` value (allows automatic line breaking). For example: `\draw [arrow] (p3) -- node[anchor=south,align=center] {it was \\ successful} (retT);`

Comment: `align` option worked clean!! Thanks again

Comment: @arunmoezhi You're welcome. I updated my answer suggesting yet another improvement (using the `positioning` library and `=of` instead of `of=`); there's a post explaining the advantages of the new syntax, but I am unable to locate it now. Tomorrow I'll search it and add the link yo my answer.